# Our iPad is asking for a 4 digit passcode that it never asked for before

Tags: ios

Our iPad is asking for a 4 digit code that it never asked for before. We updated several apps at one time. The iPad said it couldn't update them with 47% battery power, so we plugged it in and ran the updates again.  Now it asks for a 4 digit pin which it never asked for before. We didn't "accidentally" set a pin, and no one else has had access to the iPad.  We have tried several 4 digit codes that we "might" have set, none that work.  What do we do now?

Comment: presumably not the same PIN it asks for after every reboot or OS update? See if it's been put into lost mode at https://www.icloud.com/#find or perhaps Restrictions have been enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Check that your iPad is not in lost mode by going [here](http://icloud.com/#find). If so, disable it by going to Find my iPhone on another iPad or iPhone or going to icloud.com on a computer and then go to Find my iPhone. Click on the device on Find my iPhone and click Lost Mode and then turn it off.

A more likely story is that someone could have enabled "Restrictions" on your iPad. There are some ways to find out this code, or to disable Restrictions all together.

Before you do any of this, just make sure that you have Restrictions enabled by going to Settings → General → Restrictions and then click on that and if you are prompted to enter a 4 digit code, just try once more at guessing the 4 digit code.

If it still does not work, plug in your iPad to a computer. Make a backup on iTunes with the current settings. Then follow [this](http://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-reset-restriction-passcode-on-iphone-ipad-using-ibackupbot/) tutorial. This is for **both** Mac and PC.

Cheers and good luck!